# hostname lookup with ping -a randomly doesn't work

Tags: networking, dns, ping

on my network I'm trying to find the hostnames for all my machines to have a better chance of physically finding the machines in question, and I'm having a puzzling issue.

When I ping -a the IP addresses, sometimes it just won't return the hostname. No error message or anything, the machine replies I just don't get the hostname. the thing is though, sometimes it will work on the same IP, and give me the hostname.

I downloaded a tool called Miridix IP ping tool, and I'm getting the same issue.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the response to the rdns query doesn't come back fast enough ping will just show the ip address. If it does it will show rdns ptr name along with the ip.

Comment: That's all it is? Network latency?

Comment: That or maybe a dns server that is having problems and returning a srvfail or nxdomain or something. you can try nslookup or host depending on your os and see if it resolves and how long it takes...